# is it possible to self join to ask for different dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, self-join

tried to search for the answer, reading posts like this: [SQL Self-join with data comparison for different days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966981/sql-self-join-with-data-comparison-for-different-days) 
but not able to quite understand how this would work in this scenario.

Would appreciate any help;

I have a table with a

- UserID (number)
- UserType (string, shows if they are Member or Guest)
- sales_date (datestamp field)
- (plus other columns like what they bought and the cost of item that I am not interested in right now)

I am trying to write a query that will tell me how many people went between being a Member and being a Guest, per month.
So I can answer questions like 
"How many people were here in September and came back in October?"
"How many people were Members in september but downgraded to become Guests in October?"
"How many people were Guests in September but upgraded to being Members in October?"

1: Is Self-join the way to go when needing to ask for 2 different date ranges from the same table/same query?

2: I am thinking I need to ask for UserID,then UserType for Sept vs UserType for October. Does this sound right? Not sure how to ask for 2 different dates

```
SELECT
      t1.UserID,
      t1.UserType as UserTypeSept,
      t2.UserType as UserTypeOct
   FROM 
      my_table t1
         join my_table t2
            on t1.UserID = t2.UserID
           AND t2.day > '2015-01-01' AND t2.day < '2015-02-01'
   where
      t1.day  >'2015-02-01' AND t1.day <'2015-03-01'
;
```

Am I thinking along the right lanes?
Even if this works, it will not tell me how many changed from "Members" to "Guests" from Sept-October, but at least show their values in 2 different columns

thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: google bigquery

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using analytical functions instead of self join which are more expensive. Your data suits for windowing data.
Please run below query and then adjust to your table.
You probably will need format printed periods and use CASE clause for transitions between following months like "Member - Guest" to more meaningful names.

```
      WITH
  members AS ( 
  SELECT 1 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType,  TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-02-01' AS sales_date 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType,TIMESTAMP '2015-02-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-02-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType,TIMESTAMP '2015-02-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-01' AS sales_date 
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2016-08-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType,TIMESTAMP '2016-03-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2016-04-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType,TIMESTAMP '2016-02-01' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS UserID, 'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-03' AS sales_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType,TIMESTAMP '2016-02-06' AS sales_date)
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  member,
  period,
  year
FROM (
  SELECT
    UserType,
    UserID,
    sales_date,
    FORMAT_DATE("%Y",DATE(sales_date)) AS year,
    CONCAT(
    FORMAT_DATE("%b",DATE(sales_date)),
    ' - ',
    FORMAT_DATE("%b", DATE(LEAD(sales_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY sales_date ASC)))
    ) AS period,
    CONCAT(UserType,' - ', LEAD(UserType,1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY sales_date ASC)) AS member
  FROM
    members
  ORDER BY
    userid )
WHERE
  member IS NOT NULL
  and year = '2016'
GROUP BY
year,
  member,
  period
```

Comment: will try it today, thanks a lot for taking the time to help. this site is awesome!

Comment: is there a way to do by month rather than single day? where it says " TIMESTAMP '2015-02-01' AS sales_date )  " could that be something like AND YEAR(sales_date)='2015' AND MONTH(sales_date)='2' kind of thing?

Comment: I edited above query to group memberships change by month instead of day, you could also narrow results to particular year, to narrow it to month you could use as following: "period = 'Jan - Feb'" where you point which month your are interested.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Is Self-join the way to go when needing to ask for 2 different date
>   ranges from the same table/same query?

Not really! It depends! In your case - see below for #2

> 2: I am thinking I need to ask for UserID,then UserType for Sept vs
>   UserType for October

I think below does what you expect.
Please note: it looks for UserType at the end of each month and uses it as a usertype for respective month.

```
/*
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-02' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-03' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-10' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-10-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-10-02' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-10-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-10-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS UserID,  'Guest' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-01' AS sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS UserID, 'Member' AS UserType, TIMESTAMP '2015-10-01' AS sales_date ) 
*/
SELECT 
  UserID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN sales_year_month = '2015-09' THEN UserTypeAtEndOfMonth END) AS UserTypeSept,
  MAX(CASE WHEN sales_year_month = '2015-10' THEN UserTypeAtEndOfMonth END) AS UserTypeOct
FROM (
  SELECT 
    UserID, 
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(sales_date)) AS sales_year_month,
    ARRAY_AGG(UserType ORDER BY sales_date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS UserTypeAtEndOfMonth
  FROM my_table 
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
GROUP BY 1
```

You can remove comments if you want to test it on sample data